# How to transfer domain when reseller is down?

Tags: domain-transfer, downtime, reseller

I have a personal domain name registered as `example.com` it is down for whole one day. The reseller website is also down and their customer care is also not responding. Thus I can't access my domain panel. Now I want to transfer that domain under another reseller. How can I do it? Or where to reach to recover it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the reseller is just a reseller from another registrar, because I have never seen an official domain registrar that ran out of business, but I have seen so many resellers that take down their own business.

So, first you should find your official registrar, then contact them.

The official registrar of the reseller can be found on the domain whois.
For example, I bought the domain example.com on my local hosting dewawebdotcom. When I checked the domain whois, the whois server says the registrar is Enom like the below image:

[image: Registar: ENOM, INC. eNom, LLC; URL: WWW.WNOM.COM]

So, in that case, just contact enom.com to allow you to manage your domain.

Some years ago, I also had a similar problem. I handled a client's domain and he didn't know where it was from (maybe just bought from a freelancer or random people). So I contacted the registrar with my own email and, after giving proof of domain ownership, I was able to manage that domain (transferred to my account).

Comment: "because I have never seen an official domain registrar that ran out of business" Yet that exists. The most "famous" one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegisterFly

Comment: **How** do you give proof of domain ownership when the domain is down and the reseller doesn't respond?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Who shows to be the registrant either in registrar whois server if displayed or more importantly even in the registrar DB? The registrar should be able to help you and you should be able to prove ownership in various ways, including invoices from reseller, proof of identity, etc. You need to go to registrar and expose the problem with reseller.

Comment: @Patrick My invoice lists the item as e.g. "yearly fee for 1 .me domain" (no specific domain names given), and the whois record only lists my reseller. And while not ideal this is, I believe, reasonably common. And, to clarify, my reseller is entirely above-board (and reliable).

Comment: "whois record only lists my reseller." If you mean as registrant, then it is wrong. If you have bad/unclear invoices, that is another topic you might want to fix with the provider of said invoice. Again, as said also in my reply, you need to go to your **registrar** and resolve the issue there.

Answer (score 5):

> The reseller website is also down and their customer care is also not responding.

It does not matter, normally.

As long as you are speaking about a gTLD, your important contact is the registrar. It is the one under contracts to perform its duties regarding your domain. He may have resellers, but at the end of the day, it is the registrar that is responsible towards the registry and ICANN.

And among its duties is the fact that it has to honour any requested change in 24 hours at most.

You can have a look at ICANN page at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/reseller-2013-05-03-en it even provides a way to handle cases of problems like yours.

The ICANN registrar agreement at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en says this:

> 3.12 Obligations Related to Provision of Registrar Services by Third Parties. Registrar is responsible for the provision of Registrar Services for all Registered Names that Registrar sponsors being performed in compliance with this Agreement, regardless of whether the Registrar Services are provided by Registrar or a third party, including a Reseller. Registrar must enter into written agreements with all of its Resellers that enable Registrar to comply with and perform all of its obligations under this Agreement.